# Duvida de como "ler" dados no firebase-database

Tags: javascript, firebase, realtime-database

Assumindo que tenho essa estrutura no banco

```html
userId : {
  Messages : {
   SenderID : {
      PushID: {
         "msg": "Mensagem"
      }
   }
}
```

Estou usando esse codigo para "Ler" tudo dentro do "userID"

```js
dbRef.child(user.uid + "/Messages").on("value", function(snap){
                        
                        obj.html(JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3));
                    });
```

mas o retorno que preciso é apenas o "msg" : "mensagem"

gostaria de saber como fazer para retornar apenas o que preciso , alguem pode me ajudar ? agradeco desde ja

Comment: Qual o contexto? Você quer aquela mensagem específica ou todas as mensagens do `UserId`?

Comment: Boa noite Guilherme, Todas as mensagens dentro de SenderID.
essa parte do banco seria um chat entre dois usuarios

Comment: Acredito que deva rever a estrutura do banco, pessoalmente eu mudaria a sua estrutura, é recomendado evitar o uso de muitos nós encadeados

Comment: Pode me dar uma ideia de estrutura ?

Comment: Na própria [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data?hl=pt-br) é usado um exemplo de chat para explicar como estruturar o banco de dados. Eu transformaria o SenderId e UserId em dois campos do PushId

Comment: Perfeito meu amigo , dei uma olhada no link da documentação que vc mandou aí , e resolvido , vou mudar a estrutura e o modo de armazenar as msgs , honestamente deste modo que eu estava tentando fazer iria ter que replicar muitos dados , e com essa ideia aí da documentação eu armazeno tudo em um único lugar onde apenas os dois usuários podem ler , agradeço amigo

Comment: Se tiver alguma dificuldade de como fazer alguma coisa edite a pergunta com o seu questionamento e avise nos comentários :)